# How to dismiss all keyboards of multiple text fields?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, resignfirstresponder

I have three text fields in one view controller and when i do the method to dismiss the keyboard for all three text fields, the view controller doesn't come out.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.namesuite.delegate = self;
    self.createpassword.delegate = self;
    self.createname.delegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I also have the `textFieldShouldReturn` function.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

This is my button function to send me to the view controller that has the text fields.

```
- (IBAction)createaccount:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"thirdsegue" sender:sender];
}
```

Comment: Debugging to determine textFieldShouldReturn function is call when click return on the keyboard or not?

Comment: make sure you are confirming to both the UITextFieldDelegate and the UITextInputDelegate protocols

Comment: What do you mean by "the view controller doesn't come out"?

Comment: What do you mean by "dismiss all keyboards"? There is only ever one keyboard.

Comment: i have another view controller that when you click the button it goes into the new view controller, without the keyboard dismissal it segues into the next view but when i add the method for all text fields, the new view controller doesn't come out and it stops debugging.

Answer (score 4):

This will help. Try this:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Hope this helps .. :)

Comment: I had several textField, like 10 of them. Resigning first responder was big pain. this one liner saved hours of coding for me. Thanks Rashad.

Comment: @Alix > Welcome. Good to hear that.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try [this control (TPKeyboardAvoiding)](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tpkeyboardavoiding) and get ride of resign and scrolling issues. Its a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.namesuite resignFirstResponder];
    [self.createpassword resignFirstResponder];
    [self.createname resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

or

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.namesuite)
    {
         [self.namesuite resignFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == self.createpassword)
    {
         [self.createpassword resignFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == self.createname)
    {
         [self.createname resignFirstResponder];
    }

return YES;
}
```

Comment: I've tried both and it still doesn't go away when i click return. :(

Comment: Show us your extra code to push the next View. Where is it?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit where is everything? I need more information. You are clicking a UIButton to go to a View with the UITextFields?

Comment: Yes, the button is in the second view and once is clicked another view controller pops up with text fields.  I took off the text fields and now still won't go.  So im guessing the problem is in the segue?

Comment: when it crashes this comes out. xcode terminating with uncaught exception of type nsexception

Comment: Can you edit your post and clarify all the information. Please step by step what happens.